# Find parameter such that the equation has periodic solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

sorry to bother but I struggle a lot with periodicity of ODEs so I got stuck a lot with this kind of problems

**Problem**

Find all possible values of $a$ such that the equation: 
$$ x^{(4)}+3a\ddot x -4a^{2}x=0$$ **has one periodic solution** that satisfies $x(0)=\dot x(0) = -\ddot x(0)$.

**My thoughts**

Well, in first place we could find the characteristic polynomial and factorize it, $\lambda^{4}+3a\lambda^{2}+4a^{2}=(\lambda^{2}-a)(\lambda^{2}+4a)=(\lambda-\sqrt{a})(\lambda+\sqrt{a})(\lambda-i\sqrt{2a})(\lambda+i\sqrt{2a})$. but even if we do this, I do not know how to relate anything of this with the fact that satisfies the condition above nor how to relate it with the equation.

Any help would be more than welcome and really really appreciated.

Thanks so much for your answers <3

Comment: Periodic solutions satisfy $\ddot x+4ax=0$ for $a>0$ and $\ddot x-ax=0$ for $a<0$. This directly gives all the possible values of $a$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but is it possible that you can elaborate a bit? I mean I don't understand how is this so direct D:

Comment: The other factor in both cases gives exponential terms, preventing periodicity. Or you can just write out the basis solutions. Then evaluate the initial condition $\ddot x(0)=-x(0)$.